# C# Accessing object properties indexer style

Tags: c#

Is there any tool,library that would allow me to access my objects properties indexer style ?

```
public class User
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

User user = new User();
user.Name = "John";

string name = user["Name"];
```

Maybe the dynamic key word could help me here ?

Comment: I'm trying to build a generic way to do some reporting stuff.

Answer (score 10):

You can use reflection to get property value by its name

```
   PropertyInfo info = user.GetType().GetProperty("Name");
   string name = (string)info.GetValue(user, null);
```

And if you want to use index for this you can try something like that

```
    public object this[string key]
    {
        get
        {
             PropertyInfo info = this.GetType().GetProperty(key);
             if(info == null)
                return null
             return info.GetValue(this, null);
        }
        set
        {
             PropertyInfo info = this.GetType().GetProperty(key);
             if(info != null)
                info.SetValue(this,value,null);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @user256034 Very much it would. But finding a property at runtime is very slow. The only way you can do it fast is with my implementation

Comment: Not as much as using a dynamic.  Dynamics are essentially compiled at runtime as needed.

Comment: Just tested - `00:00:00.0005115` time to execute `string name = (string)user["Name"];`

Comment: Dynamic is using reflection under the hood but it is also using some smart caching so the performance should be better then reflection.

Comment: I don't think Dynamic is using reflection under the hood. dynamic requires the DLR (Dynamic Language Runtime), which it would not require if all it was doing was reflection.  Dynamics are defered by the compiler and then when they are encountered at run time the DLR spins up an evaluates them.

Comment: See this test app - http://geekswithblogs.net/SunnyCoder/archive/2009/06/26/c-4.0-dynamics-vs.-reflection.aspx. Reflection **is slower** than dynamic

Answer (score 3):

Check out [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2549tw02.aspx) about indexers. The dictionary stores all the values and keys instead of using properties. This way you can add new properties at runtime without losing performance

```
public class User
{
    Dictionary<string, string> Values = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    public string this[string key]
        {
            get
            {
                return Values[key];
            }
            set
            {
                Values[key] = value;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: There're many object so implementing this for every object isn't an option.

Comment: @user256034 You only do that once and store the values in the dictionary instead of properties.

Answer (score 2):

You could certainly inherit DynamicObject and do it that way.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.trygetindex.aspx

Using the simple indexer method mentioned here by others would limit you to either returning only 'object' (and having to cast) or having only string types in your class.

**Edit**: As mentioned elsewhere, even with dynamic, you still need to use either reflection or some form of lookup to retrieve the value inside the TryGetIndex function.

Comment: @user256034 The link above has a decent example.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this until the class implements a Indexer.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to access a property based on a string value you could use reflection to do something similar:

```
string name = typeof(User).GetProperty("Name").GetValue(user,null).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could build it yourself with reflection and indexer.

But for what do you need such a solution?